# String Replace - address abbreviations

Tags: regex, validation, mariadb

Essentionally I have a column for street address (e.g. 321 North Laredo Road).  This column has 10,000+ records.  Some Records are completely unabbreviated some are partially and some are completely.  Point being no consistency (it was like this before I had access).  I need to make all addresses's Directionals (N,S,E,W) and street names (road, blvd, ave, etc) into the abbreviated forms and add to a second column.  any suggestions with methodology or possibly an already written solution.  getting mixed results with following test code. . .

```
/* First find/update directionals */
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'North', 'N')
where street LIKE "%North%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'South', 'S')
where street LIKE "%South%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'East', 'E')
where street LIKE "%East%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'West', 'W')
where street LIKE "%West%"
;
/* Second look for streets to abbreviate */    
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Alley', 'Aly')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Alley%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Anex', 'Anx')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Anex%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Arcade', 'Arc')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Arcade%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Avenue', 'Ave')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Avenue%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Bayou', 'Byu')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Bayou%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Beach', 'Bch')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Beach%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Bend', 'Bnd')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Bend%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Bluff', 'Blf')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Bluff%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Bluff', 'Blfs')
where tiger_address LIKE "%Bluffs%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Street', 'St')
where tiger_address LIKE "%street%"
;

UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(street, 'Road', 'Rd')
where tiger_address LIKE "%road%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Drive', 'Dr')
where tiger_address LIKE "drive%"
;
UPDATE hospital
set tiger_address = replace(tiger_address, 'Boulevard', 'Blvd')
where tiger_address LIKE "boulevard%"
;
```

The age old there has to be a better way. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Deleting one chunk out of a word can be accomplished using MariaDB's `regexp_replace` and [positive look-ahead and look-behind assertions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/pcre/#named-subpatterns-and-backreferences). For Bayou and Boulevard I use `replace`.

```
select replace(replace(
  regexp_replace(
    'North East South West Alley Anex Arcade Avenue '
    'Bayou Beach Bend Bluff Bluffs Street Road Drive Boulevard',

    '(?<=N)orth|(?<=S)outh|(?<=E)ast|(?<=W)est|(?<=Al)le(?=y)|'
    '(?<=An)e(?=x)|(?<=Arc)ade|(?<=Ave)nue|(?<=B)ea(?=ch)|(?<=B)e(?=nd)|'
    '(?<=Bl)uf(?=f)|(?<=St)reet|(?<=R)oa(?=d)|(?<=Dr)ive',

    ''),
  'Bayou', 'Byu'),
  'Boulevard', 'Blvd')
```